# Performance: Script vs Expression

Tags: camunda

I would like to know in camunda which one is efficient? Is it script(js/groovy) or expression(${beans})?
Expression can be beans or delegate Classes or any other classes.
script can be groovy or javascript codes where developer write piece of code to transform data or constuct payload to upcoming http-connector.

Answer (score 0):

In Camunda 7 Scripts are executed on server side and cached, so there is likely very little difference compared to an expression evaluation calling a bean method.

It is not a question I would lose sleep over. There are likely x other areas in your solution that will benefit more from performance tuning.